# canon printers with ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, printing, canon

Since upgrading to ubuntu 20.04 I am struggling with my canon printer. It prints 3~10 pages then get stuck. I have to restart my printer and PC for it to resume. I tried reinstalling the driver but this problem is still there :(

My canon printer is MF231

Edit: my ubuntu version is 20.04

**Solution**: I'm not exactly sure WHY this problem came to be since updating to ubuntu 20, but while following [this link](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingPrintingProblems), it was completely solved when I followed the first 5 steps:

> 1. Make sure that the printer is connected to your system and powered on.
> 2. Open a terminal/console and check if the usb kernel modules are
>    loaded:
>
> `$ lsmod | grep usb`
>
> 3. Unplug the USB printer cable from your computer and enter this
>    command:
>
> `$ tail -f /var/log/syslog`
>
> 4. Reconnect the USB printer cable,
>    you should see some messages appearing.
> 5. Press Ctrl-C to stop the logging.

Comment: @codlord please make it into a reply to give you the bounty, that link worked for me! thank you so much!

Comment: o.k. but please update your post or add a comment to say what fixed it for you so the question is useful for others who may find it in future.

Answer (score 1):

How is your printer connected to your PC? USB, Network cable, wireless? Exactly which driver/version are you installing/re-installing? Where did you get the driver from?

And I suggest you elaborate on "get stuck" as that does not tell people anything. Do you mean it jams? Simply stops printing? Does the job queue still show a job when this happens? Can you delete the job from the job queue? Edit your original question with the results of lpstat -t

Have you gone through this page? [wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingPrintingProblems](http://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingPrintingProblems)